# Problems with For... Next Statements in Vb. Net

Tags: vb.net, loops

This is my code so far

---

```
        For intArrayCheck = 0 To 16
            foo = sender.name
            If foo = strShipsLocationArray(intArrayCheck) Then
                MessageBox.Show("You got a ship down!")
                sender.backcolor = Color.Red
            End If
        Next
```

What I want the code to do is if foo is not equal to any strings in strShipLocationsArray then

---

```
        sender.backcolor = Color.Blue
```

How do I do this?

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set it to blue before entering the loop. So if will change `If foo=strShipsLocationArray(intArrayCheck)`, otherwise it will stay blue

Answer (score 1):

Always set it to blue before your loop. That way if it is never set to red during the loop, it'll still be blue afterwards, so the final result will always be as required.

If setting that property has an immediate side effect, use a temporary variable and assign it to sender.backcolor after the loop finishes.